# Sudden loss of References in Visual Studio 2010 Desktop program

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

While doing some updates to my project (Removing the need to use a database for configuration information via Compact SQL 3.5) I removed the references to `system.data`, `system.data.datasetexentions`, and `syste.dataSQlServerCE`.

of course VS 'freaked' out with errors in reference to the data tables and connections which is what I expected (and wanted)

however, this morning, Visual Studio is freaking out over forms and type definitions with errors like:

> Error 51  Type 'System.Windows.Forms.Padding' is not defined. 
>   C:\Users\Visual Studio
>   Projects\VS2010\TK_NoDB\Forms\frmReports.Designer.vb
>
> Error 101 Type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' is not defined.
>   C:\Users\Visual Studio
>   Projects\VS2010\TK_NoDB\Forms\rptCheckList.Designer.vb
>
> Error 72  Type 'System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode' is not
>   defined.  C:\Users\Visual Studio
>   Projects\VS2010\TK_NoDB\Forms\rptCheckList.Designer.vb

(over 100 over them!)

anyone have an idea of what the heck I might have done and how to fix it?

What I've done so far:

1. removed and readded all the references (didn't work, same errors)
2. Noticed that that intellisence wants to change some of the references from
   System.ComponentModel.IContainer to Global.System.ComponentModel.IContainer
3. Readded the database references (and removed them again)
4. Verified that the Target Framework matches the framework references.

Comment: Did you have removed the references to System and System.Windows.Forms?

Comment: Yes. ( I just updated the question with what I've done so far. )

Comment: The DebuggerNonUserCode attribute is defined in mscorlib.dll, a reference that you cannot remove.  The more likely explanation is that you've declared a namespace or class that's named "System" so it hides the System namespace.

Comment: Thank you, Hans.  It was working yesterday, and I know I didn't add a class/function/what ever called 'system'.   However, I will look though the code and report back.

Comment: I think I found the problem.  There was a Class buried in code that was referencing the system.dataSQlServerCE once that was removed things seem to be working properly.   Thank you, again, Hans for the point in the right direction.